# Google Console - How to add Authorized redirect URIs via API

Tags: google-api, google-developers-console

Whenever I want to add any authorized redirect URI in the credentials section, I must have to google console and add it. Is there any API available that I can use in the script, I have googled it a lot but couldn't find anything related to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no api that will allow you to programmatically add redirect uris to your project on google console.

Google console is configuration for the developer its not something that should be needed to be done programmatically.

Comment: The problem is google console is too slow and we are getting these requests again and again.

Comment: Im sorry that statement doesn't make any sense.   When you add a new redirect uri for your application it should work within 5 minutes.   Why would you need to add them again.  You should only need one per application.

Comment: I have 1000 authorized redirect uris. we are using subdomains. we need to whitelist subdomain everytime it is added.

Comment: This is all the same app?  If so then im surprised you haven't hit the redirect uri limit.

Comment: yea.. same app. I don't know what is the limit for it. but yea it is working fine at the moment.

Comment: Either way your going to have to add them manually there is no api. I have been asking for one for about ten years.  Nothing yet.